# How can I set a div to full responsive height. (fiddle link included)

Tags: html, css, web

I am making a 30/70 design with left the navigation and in the right the content. When I load my page it sets the height to 100%, but when I scroll he does not update its height and the result is that I get to see my background color instead of the divs background color. I went through several similar questions and tried it but then my navigation blow up.

I got a JS [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v2z8t5gf/)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#overzicht {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    z-index: 999;
}

#nav {
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here you can see the result when you scroll it doesn't update the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out line 52 ( `#overzicht-instructies {height: 100%;}` ) and it seems to work how I think you want it to. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2z8t5gf/1/

By setting an explicit height, it's relative to the window size (I think specifically the 'viewport', although I could be mistaken on that).

I'm guessing you set the height because you wanted to make sure that both columns would take up the full height of the page regardless of how much content was in each. That's a little tougher to do, but you can set min-height values instead of height values (`html, body, .containerClass {min-height:100%;/*height:auto;*/}`) and it at least won't restrict the height of your containers to the window height.

Answer (score 2):

Set `html, body` to `min-height: 100%` that will allow to stretch the body beyond the browser viewport height.

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/72xy3zuc/)

```css
/* ------------------------------------------------------ */


/* MAIN FILE - MAP */


/* ------------------------------------------------------ */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
html {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
p,
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #95a5a6;
}
p {
    font-size: 80%;
}
#nav {
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav p {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
#overzicht {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    z-index: 999;
}
#overzicht-instructies {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    z-index: 999;
    color: #000;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #414141;
}
h2:after {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    content: " ";
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*-- NAV --*/

a:link,
a:visited {}
a:hover,
a:active {}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
.navi {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
ul li a:link,
ul li a:visited {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.28);
}
ul li a:hover,
ul li a:active {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-left: 5px solid #2980b9;
}
.icons {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.current-page {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-left: 5px solid #e67e22;
}
.current-page {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-left: 5px solid #e67e22;
}

/*-- TABEL --*/

table {
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
}
tr {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
th {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}

/*-- Tabelnamen --*/

th {
    background: #2980b9;
    border: none;
}

/*-- Tabeldata --*/

td {
    background: #3498db;
    border: none;
}
.section-tabel {
    text-align: center;
}

/*-- BUTTONS --*/

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #474D5A;
    border: 3px dashed #a2a7b7;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
    background-color: #474D5A;
    color: #00FA9A;
    border: 3px dashed #00FA9A;
}
.brenso {
    background-color: #3498db;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    color: #fff;
}
.slider {}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    width: 50px;
    color: #ccc;
    font-style: italic;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    color: #00FA9A;
    font-style: normal;
}
.test {
    color: #2980b9;
}
.vandaag-context table {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.morgen-context table {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.morgen-context table a:link,
.morgen-context table a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background: #f39c12;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d48506;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #d48506;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #d48506;
}
.morgen-context table a:active {
    top: 1px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
p {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
.info {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.info p {
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.rondje {
    color: #e67e22;
    border: 2px solid #e67e22;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Webapp voor de werknemers van het bedrijf Brenso, om gemakkelijker hun bestemmingen visueel aan te kaarten en te voltooien.">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recources/css/overzicht.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recources/css/queries.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Brenso WebApp</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="header-nav">
            <nav>
                <div class="row">
                    <h1 style="clear: both;" class="brenso">Brenso Geolocation</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="navi" href="main.php"><i class="ion-map icons"></i>Kaart</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="navi" href="overzicht.php"><i class="ion-ios-list icons"></i>Overzicht</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navi current-page" href="instructie.html"><i class="ion-help-circled icons"></i>Handleiding</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navi" href="index.html" onclick="return confirm('Ben je zeker dat je wilt uitloggen?')"><i class="ion-log-out icons"></i>Log uit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section id="overzicht-instructies" class="section-tabel">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Algemene informatie</h2>
            <div class="info">
                <p>Deze applicatie is gemaakt voor het <strong>visualiseren van klantenafspraken</strong>. Het doel is om een duidelijk beeld te krijgen over wat je nog moet doen vandaag en daar interactief mee omgaan.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Stappenplan</h2>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="rondje">1</div>
                <p>Deze applicatie is gemaakt voor het <strong>visualiseren van klantenafspraken</strong>. Het doel is om een duidelijk beeld te krijgen over wat je nog moet doen vandaag en daar interactief mee omgaan.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="rondje">2</div>
                <p>Deze applicatie is gemaakt voor het <strong>visualiseren van klantenafspraken</strong>. Het doel is om een duidelijk beeld te krijgen over wat je nog moet doen vandaag en daar interactief mee omgaan.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="rondje">3</div>
                <p>Deze applicatie is gemaakt voor het <strong>visualiseren van klantenafspraken</strong>. Het doel is om een duidelijk beeld te krijgen over wat je nog moet doen vandaag en daar interactief mee omgaan.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are giving `body` a fixed `height` of 100%. Replace your height definition to use `min-height: 100%` and `body` will be at least the height of the viewport but if the document's content exceeds this height then `body` will expand to contain it.

```
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Updating the `#overzicht-instructies` `height:100%` as `min-height:100%`